# Poisson Distribution standard deviation

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

in a normal distribution, one standard deviation above and below the mean encompasses 68% of data. Can this also apply to Poisson distribution? in not, how can you tell how much of data falls between standard deviations for Poisson distribution? a reference to the answer would be great too.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends strongly on the parameter $\lambda$. For large $\lambda$, it's close to the normal version by the Central Limit Theorem. For small $\lambda$, it's quite irregular, with jumps every time $\lambda+\sqrt{\lambda}$ or $\lambda-\sqrt{\lambda}$ crosses an integer.

Here's a graph of that behavior for $\lambda < 4$. The vertical axis is how much of the Poisson distribution is within one standard deviation of the mean, and the horizontal axis is the parameter $\lambda$.

[image: Graph]